# Split the list element in prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a problem in split prolog list element.I have some list of atom.If the atom is find in my prolog list then it is split by two words.
**My code**.

```
list-->[acar]|[avan]|[ajeep]|[abicycle].

%expected answer
?- split([i,have,acar],L2).
L2=[i,have,a,car];

?- split([there,is,avan,and,acar],L2).
L2=[there,is,a,van,and,a,car];
```

I couldn't get better way.Any idea to solve this problem.Thank you...

Comment: That's a strange predicate. Why would the first expected result not split `acar` but your second example splits `avan` and `acar`?

Comment: @lurker sorry for that. that is also split, see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this:

```
list(car)-->[acar].
list(van)-->[avan].
list(jeep)-->[ajeep].
list(bicycle)-->[abicycle].

split(In,X):-list(W,[L],[]),append(A,[L|T],In),append(A,[a,W|T],X1),split(X1,X),!.
split(L,L).
```

**Edit**

`split_a(X):-list([L],[]),atom_length(L,S),N is S-1,sub_atom(L,1,N,_,X).`

Comment: It is ok but how can i use dcg rule as only one like `list-->` because if lots of words come difficult to write that way.

Comment: Yes you can do it that way.see the <b>Edit</b> Here `sub_atom/5` you can split the atom as without `a`.then you can use the atom for previous `split` word as `W`.In this answer you can use `list`like your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments.